# Explorer tree auto tracking in windows?

Tags: windows-7, window

Looking at this picture :

[image]

First I clicked on #1 , then navigated deeply into `c:\inetpub\logs` but still , the left pane is on `RN(C:)`

Is there any option to make it auto change while navigating in the right pane ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left pane behavior of Windows Explorer in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/84121/), [Windows 7 Explorer tree view expand](http://superuser.com/questions/272117/),  [Can I make Windows Explorer Treeview show folders in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/363121/), [Why doesn't File browser scroll to current folder in Windows7?](http://superuser.com/questions/298629/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Tools > Folder Options`. Now in the first `General` tab under `Navigation Pane` section you will see a checkbox `Automatically expand to current folder`. Make sure it's checked.

Comment: Tnx working  ^_^